# Linux: Linking with Alsa undefined references

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ld, undefined-reference, alsa

Experienced C++ dev here (although not a whole lot of in-depth experience with the underlying details of compilers/linking). I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, and can't seem to link against the alsa library. I have libasound2-dev installed with gcc 9.2.1.

The code I'm using is from here https://gist.github.com/albanpeignier/104902

My compile output is:

```
↳ g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so main.cpp

/tmp/cc9z8wYv.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_open'
main.cpp:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
main.cpp:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc'
main.cpp:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
main.cpp:(.text+0x130): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_any'
main.cpp:(.text+0x147): undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1ba): undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
main.cpp:(.text+0x214): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format'
main.cpp:(.text+0x22b): undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
main.cpp:(.text+0x288): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near'
main.cpp:(.text+0x29f): undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2fb): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels'
main.cpp:(.text+0x312): undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
main.cpp:(.text+0x369): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params'
main.cpp:(.text+0x380): undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3d0): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_free'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3fa): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_prepare'
main.cpp:(.text+0x411): undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
main.cpp:(.text+0x45f): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_format_width'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4b8): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_readi'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4d2): undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
main.cpp:(.text+0x556): undefined reference to `snd_pcm_close'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(I also get the same error if I just use -lasound)

Here's where it gets confusing, here are the symbols from libasound.so:

```
↳ nm -gD /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so
                 U accept
                 U access
0000000000000000 A ALSA_0.9
0000000000000000 A ALSA_0.9.0
0000000000000000 A ALSA_0.9.0rc4
0000000000000000 A ALSA_0.9.0rc8
0000000000000000 A ALSA_0.9.3
0000000000000000 A ALSA_0.9.5
0000000000000000 A ALSA_0.9.7
00000000000ba0b0 T alsa_lisp
00000000000ba390 T alsa_lisp_default_cfg
00000000000ba460 T alsa_lisp_default_cfg_free
00000000000b9f00 T alsa_lisp_free
00000000000ba490 T alsa_lisp_function
000000000002aea0 T alsa_lisp_init_objects
00000000002ff7a0 B alsa_lisp_nil
00000000000ba970 T alsa_lisp_result_free
00000000000ba9e0 T alsa_lisp_seq_count
00000000000ba980 T alsa_lisp_seq_first
00000000000baa20 T alsa_lisp_seq_integer
00000000000ba9a0 T alsa_lisp_seq_next
00000000000baa60 T alsa_lisp_seq_pointer
00000000002ff7e0 B alsa_lisp_t
                 U __assert_fail
                 U bind
...
0000000000077190 T _snd_pcm_null_open
0000000000076f80 T snd_pcm_null_open
00000000002ff778 B __snd_pcm_null_open_dlsym_pcm_001
000000000004e240 T snd_pcm_open
000000000004e330 T snd_pcm_open_fallback
000000000004e2d0 T snd_pcm_open_lconf
...
```

In the (huge) list of symbols above, at least 'snd_pcm_open' is listed - so why do I get undefined references to it?

What am I missing? What else can I try?

Answer (score 2):

Encountered the same issue today, resolved it by reordering my linking parameters as detailed in [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409470/8738498).

That is, `gcc -lasound main.c` becomes `gcc main.c -lasound`.

Unsure why the ordering is pertinent to this particular instance, given that `gcc` usually doesn't seem to care.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on my own; but it doesn't address the heart of the problem.

As I mentioned, I was using GCC 9.2.1. From what I can tell, installing GCC 9.2.1 caused some sort of issue somewhere in the tool-chain. Not only would the alsa library not link properly, but also the X11 library.

The solution was to go nuclear and re-install Ubuntu.. which I had been planning to do for a while to have a clean upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04. After install 18.04 everything worked fine.